# How to control screen processes using python

Tags: python, unix, gnu-screen

I'm trying to piece together some Python code to control UNIX screen processes (/usr/bin/screen) as part of a script to ease on-server deployment.   Are there any libraries or modules that could facilitate this?  Is there a better way to do this than just using a standard Python subprocess?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're exactly looking for, but you might want to take a look at [byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) source code as an example about how to enhance screen.

Comment: I was wondering if there was some nice API -- ideally in Python -- out there to control /usr/bin/screen instead of wrapping command line commands in subprocesses.

Comment: This honestly sounds like a job more suited to bash. Does it need to be python?

Comment: If I may ask, what exactly in your server deployment process requires screen?

Comment: We run most of our processes through screen rather than as daemons, since this makes it in many ways easier to check the status of our deployed processes and to interact with their CLI.

Comment: Ideally the screen-control solution would be in Python, but any APIs or tools to simplify the process would be helpful.

Comment: If you're using it for productive systems, maybe adding scripting support for screen would be an option. Additionally, your patches might be integrated upstream to improve the screen experience for the rest of the world.

Comment: You might look at the source of [this Vim script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2711) or similar things and see how they do it.

Comment: If you have a solution, you should post it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution.  There's a Python module called [screenutils](https://github.com/Christophe31/screenutils).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/2.4).

There is also a fork: [pexpect-u](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect-u/2.5)

I'm not 100% certain there isn't any limitations in [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect-u/2.5) compared to [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm), but if you find any you can always try your hand at some tcl :)

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to use screen? Because what you need sounds just like what "fabric" (made in Python)  was designed for: controlling multiple remote servers from Python scripts or interactive shell.

Here is a ink to fabric overview:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/index.html